# How to fix page layout with embedded frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

So I'm trying to fix the layout of my page so that I have a speckle frame on the left side of the page and a few charts on the right - like the image below.

[image: ideal layout]

At the moment, my charts are going underneath the other sections.

Here is my html:

```css
.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Left and right column */

.column.side {
  width: 30%;
}


/* Middle column */

.column.middle {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>

<div class="column middle">
  <iframe src="https://hestia.speckle.works/#/embed/li0TtsHb3F" width="100%" height=500px> </iframe>
</div>

<div class="column side">
  <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If u want this equal width then, u can add width:50%; for column class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the `middle` column is currently flowing below the `side` column is because there is a padding of 10px (20px if you add the left and right side) around each column.

You can think of it as: `30% + 20px + 70% + 20px`.

This can either be fixed by change to `box-sizing: border-box` so that the padding is included in the `%` width of the div, or can be solved with CSS Flexbox.

With Flexbox - you would need to wrap your columns with a `row` class and change
 the css.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column middle">
        <iframe
          src="https://hestia.speckle.works/#/embed/li0TtsHb3F"
          width="100%"
          height="500px"
        >
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="column side">
        <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

/* Left and right column */
.column.side {
    flex-basis: 30%;
}

/* Middle column */
.column.middle {
    flex-basis: 70%;
}
```